# How to create 3d boxes in matplotlib chart and count total number of point in each box?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, scatter, voxel

I have a 3d scatter chart as shown in the image. I have to divide the axis and create set of 3d boxes in chart and count total number of point in each 3d box. Can anybody tell me how to create 3d boxes in the chart and count number of points in every box.

Here i have used [crowd_temperature dataset](https://crawdad.org/queensu/crowd_temperature/20151120/temperature/) to generate scatter plot.
[image]

Comment: `numpy` has a 2D histogram function. You should use that and then loop through the z-axis

Comment: can you please send me link to some same code which could make it easy to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a 3D histogram using `np.histogramdd()` where you set up your bins along your x, y, and z axis. You can find the documentation on how to use the function [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html). If you would like more help in solving your problem please provide sample code.

On another note, there are probably better ways to visualize your data. I think you will find it rather difficult to visualize this 3D histogram in a meaningful way. Try taking a latitude vs. temperature approach or just do a latitude vs. longitude histogram to see the spatial distribution of data.

Comment: I really needed a help. thank you  very much :)  How can i communicate the code,data and full concept with you?